# Definition of algebra of polynomial functions on a vector space.

Tags: ring-theory, vector-spaces, zariski-topology

In his lectures nots on [Topology](https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Enacinovi/files/topologia.pdf), Prof. Nacinovich gives as an example of topological space the Zariski Topology on a vector space. To this end, he says

> Let $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over a field $\Bbb K$. Let $\mathscr{A}(V)$ be the $\Bbb K$-algebra of the polynomial functions on $V$ with values in $\Bbb K$. Let us denote by $\mathfrak{C}$ the class of sets of the form
> $$ C(F) = \{ v \in V : f(v) = 0 \quad \forall f \in F\} $$
> when $F$ ranges among the subsets of $\mathscr{A}(V)$.

Does anyone know the definition of polynomial functions on a vector space? I have tried to read it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_polynomial_functions) but it is not that clear.

Comment: Fix a basis $e_i$. You have the monomials $x_i$, which are the functions that take a point and output the $i$th coordinate. You can then create polynomials out of these monomials, which you evaluate on points by evaluating the monomials and then combining with $+, \times$ appropriately. The resulting space of functions is independent of the basis. You can also do this in a basis free way by building polynomials out of the linear functionals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formally, the polynomial functions on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ are given by the [symmetric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra) $S(V^{\ast})$ on the [dual vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) $V^{\ast}$. The idea is to think of the elements of $V^{\ast}$ as the homogeneous polynomial functions on $V$ of degree $1$ and then take sums and products of these. You can check that if you pick a basis $e_1, \dots e_n$ of $V$ then $S(V^{\ast})$ can be identified with the algebra of polynomials $k[f_1, \dots f_n]$ on the dual basis of $e_i$.

Note that when the underlying field $k = \mathbb{F}_q$ is finite a polynomial function on $V$ is not faithfully determined by its action on the underlying set of $V$ (for any polynomial $f(x)$, the polynomial $f(x^q)$ determines the same function); this commonly trips up beginners. However, it is faithfully determined by its action on the tensor products $V \otimes_k L$ as $L$ ranges over all extensions (even all finite extensions suffices) of $k$. This is a small hint of the [functor of points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_represented_by_a_scheme#Functor_of_points) approach to algebraic geometry.